# (Javascript) Why doesn't function take parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a NodeJS stuff, the code is:

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

My question is how come in the last line, the function onRequest doesn't take parameters.. I'm new to Javascript but isn't onRequest supposed to take 2 parameters as defined in the function? Can anyone help me please? I've been stuck for an hour :(

Comment: onRequest does take two params, request and response. createServer takes one argument, the event function.

Comment: Functions are objects. `onRequest` is a function object. `onRequest()` calls the function `onRequest` and returns its value.

Comment: @john, were any answers helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution of the onRequest function takes 2 parameters.

Your last line:

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

does not actually execute onRequest, though I can see why you would think it does.  It passes a reference to the onRequest function to the http.createServer function / method.

createServer will save a pointer to your onRequest function and then when a request comes into the server, it will execute onRequest.  That execution will include a request and response argument.

For details, this article gives a fairly straightforward and concise explanation of this pattern, known as callbacks.  It typically goes with asynchronous programming, but doesn't have to.

http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually calling the method. You're telling `createServer` what its `requestListener` callback function is.

From the node.js documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener):

> http.createServer([requestListener])
>
> Returns a new web server object.
>
> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the
>   'request' event.